# How to make Nokia Lumia 635 RM-975 display on pc after windows 10 new update?

Tags: lumia

After the latest windows 10 update, my Nokia Lumia 635 RM-975 does no longer appear when connected to the Pc. When i try to update the drivers automatically, it says :

A service installation section in this INF is invalid.

When i try to browse my computer for software and try to pick on the list of devices, after installation, i can not access the phone content as i used to previously.

How to make Nokia Lumia 635 RM-975 display on pc after windows 10 new update ?

Comment: Is it showing this error on the phone, or the PC? What OS is the PC running? Are you running an insider build at all?

Comment: The error is showing on Windows 10 pro. It use to work properly until windows pushed a new update and after that, it no longer displays the phone when i connect it to the laptop and when i try to update the drivers, it says `A service installation section in this INF is invalid.`